# How to run multiple Kubernetes jobs in sequence?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to run a sequence of Kubernetes jobs one after another. It's okay if they are run on different nodes, but it's important that each one run to completion before the next one starts. Is there anything built into Kubernetes to facilitate this? Other architecture recommendations also welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This requirement to add control flow, even if it's a simple sequential flow, is outside the scope of Kubernetes native entities as far as I know.
There are many workflow engine implementations for Kubernetes, most of them are focusing on solving CI/CD but are generic enough for you to use however you want.

- Argo: https://applatix.com/open-source/argo/ 
  Added a custom resource deginition in Kubernetes entity for Workflow
- Brigade: https://brigade.sh/
  Takes a more serverless like approach and is built on Javascript which is very flexible
- Codefresh: https://codefresh.io
  Has a unique approach where you can use the SaaS to easily get started without complicated installation and maintenance, and you can point Codefresh at your Kubernetes nodes to run the workflow on.

Feel free to Google for "Kubernetes Workflow", and discover the right platform for yourself.

Disclaimer: I work at Codefresh

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on [IBM TWS (Workload Automation)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/distr/src_ref/awsrgchdccabb.htm) which is a scheduler similar to cronjob where you can mention the dependencies of the jobs.

You can specify a job to run only after it's dependencies has run using **follows** keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [cronjobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) and set the [concurrency policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy) to forbid so it doesn't run concurrent jobs.